# How to filter category posts based on a parameter on a woocommerce website?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm creating a widget with links that should filter the products in a category page. That is easily achieved with the pre_get_posts hook, but I wanted to provide some special parameters as input to the filter.

For example: 
http://mysite/product-category/churros/?ingredients=milk

Obviously I can't access $_GET in my action that runs on pre_get_posts, so how could I achieve this?

Thanks a mil!

Comment: 'Obviously I can't access $_GET in my action that runs on pre_get_posts' - Why not? There's nothing to prevent you from using `$_GET`

Comment: You can also access GET parameter by using [get_query_var( 'ingredients')](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var).